# repo for all except some projects not all. is there a repo command to do this?

Tags: android, linux, git, repo

I have tried googling this but havent found anything relavant to what im looking for.
I have a few projects in android that i have rebased to the tip. After doing that I would like to move all the remaining projects to the tip.

The below command will checkout all the projects to the tag. 
repo forall -c "git checkout "

I would like to skip the ones that i have rebased manually.

Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you need to do this. What's the problem with using  `repo sync`?

Answer (score 7):

With `repo forall` you can specify which projects the command should apply to, but there's no way of expressing "all projects except these *N* projects" (unless you can express the projects you want it to apply to using a regular expression, but that's not likely).

What you can do is produce a list of all projects, e.g. with

```
repo forall -c 'echo $REPO_PROJECT'
```

and remove the projects you've rebased and want to exclude, e.g. by piping the output to `grep -v` or by redirecting the output to a file and editing that file by hand. Then feed that project list to `repo forall`. Two examples:

```
repo forall -c 'echo $REPO_PROJECT' > projects
vi projects
repo forall $(cat projects) -c 'git checkout'

repo forall $(repo forall -c 'echo $REPO_PROJECT' | grep -v name/of/project) -c 'git checkout'
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `-i` or `-r`. i.e. `repo forall -i bypass git fetch`

```
-r, --regex           Execute the command only on projects matching regex or
                    wildcard expression
-i, --inverse-regex   Execute the command only on projects not matching
                    regex or wildcard expression
```

Comment: The -i flag is not available on versions pre 1.12.34